# Cordova Barcode Scanner: keep camera on

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, barcode-scanner

I'm using Ionic to develop a scan application to validate tickets at events. Since their are usually large cues, the focus of the app is speed.
I'm using [BarcodeScanner plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner) for Cordova. Out of the box, a scan action opens the camera, scans a code, closes the camera, and then gives me the code. Since opening and closing the camera takes up time, I would like to change this plugin to keeping the camera open, and having a popup on top of the camera feed when a code is scanned.

I know I probably have to change the source files of the plugin, but I have no idea where to start. Maybe someone else has experience with this?

Any other free Cordova plugin which supports this is fine too. Or maybe use a Barcode Scanner written in JS, like [QuaggaJS](https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/)? How would I implement this in my Ionic app? Because I figure I'll need to have camera access permission.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this problem is not about the plugin which you are using, the issue is your mobile is loaded with full of app's i think and it may have  less ram memory so that's why it will take some time to open and closing the camera